# How to group each n-element in Scala together?

Tags: scala

I have the following list `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7, ... )` I want a list that is groups each n-elements together. For example, every 2 elements would give `List((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8), .... )` every 3 elemenets `List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))` etc.

Comment: This is the kind of questions that you can answer yourself by looking at the [**docs**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

list.grouped(2).toList // List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5, 6), List(7))
```

Note that the last entry has only 1 element as there are an odd number of elements in the `List`

The `toList` is required because `grouped` returns an `iterator`, but in most cases you can just process the `iterator` directly and don't need to convert back to `List`.

Comment: I knew it has to be easy in Scala :D

Comment: If you like that, you'll love `sliding` :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `grouped` function, like this:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).grouped(3)
result: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7))
```

Comment: This is not quite right, `grouped` actually returns an `iterator`. You need to add `toList` if you want the result as a `List`